# Unique strings for geographical areas

Tags: geolocation

Is there any joint effort project to generate a database table of -unique- strings for geographical areas (like Oslo would be listed as just "Oslo" because there is only one Oslo, whereas Victoria would be listed both as "Victoria, Australia" and "Victoria, British Columbia".)

"Areas" would be approximately "second level administrative divisions", like U.S. Counties, Norwegian "kommuner" and Dutch "geemente", though countries with complex geographical systems would have to be individually handled.

If there is no such project and anyone would like to start one, please indicate your interest.  It would be a side project to Geonames, or possibly integrate into it.  Geonames has no world-unique string like this to my knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

Um... [geonames.org](http://www.geonames.org/)?

Comment: Geonames has no database column containing World-unique string like "Victoria, Australia"? But if it does, it will resolve my request.

Comment: @forthrin i believe geonames has info on their website, you should try there.

Comment: Where? There is no such string in the allCountries table. Every "Victoria" is listed as just "Victoria". They are not distinguished into a (comma-separated) string which is unique for the World (eg. "Victoria, Australia" and "Victoria, British Columbia".

Comment: @forthrin then that probably answers your question.  The table data has name (Victoria) in one column and Country in a separate.  It is not in a string combined.

Comment: This is a more complex situation than just slapping on the country name. There are numerous places called "San Jose" in the world, several in the US, some in Colombia, some in Spain and many others too. All of them would have to receive a unique string. Administrative data in Geonames is very lacking at times, so this cannot simply be automated with a script. Manual labour is required.

Comment: @forthrin: still, geonames.org comes pretty close to what you need, and using it as starting point is much more likely to succeed than looking for another DB that does exactly what you want. And I'm pretty sure it's not difficult at all to fully automate the creation of a unique descriptive String since you can detect collisions (where towns of the same name in the same country lack distinguishing administrative data) and use fallback strategies for only those cases, e.g. part of latitude/longitude. I suspect that this would occur very rarely.

Comment: @forthrin: I just did a quick check: of the 87000 entries in the biggest cities DB of geonames org, there are just 590 entries where name+country+admin1+admin2 is not unique.

Comment: I am looking for areas, not cities. Each country must be represented with all areas, so that a user can choose his area no matter where he lives. The "area" must correspond to a U.S. county or a Scandinavian "kommune" as well as possible. The admin level data in Geonames is scarce at best, and missing for many countries. Some countries also have complex/unclear systems for this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_administrative_divisions_by_country

Comment: @forthrin: ah, now it starts to sound like a project of its own. And like a massive headache; it's more a domain problem than a programming problem.

Comment: Exactly. I assume many sites need this type of functionality, therefore it would benefit the common good to share the workload of creating a well-organized system for this. Maybe this is not the right place to ask? Maybe try the Geonames forum? But I'd be interested in hearing how other people have handled this.

Comment: @forthrin: you're definitely more likely to get useful information in GIS-related forums. As for how others have handled this, that depends on what you need the information for.